# How can i switch dynamically between two databases

Tags: php, mysql

Hello guys am coming up with an admin dashboard ,but i need my system to switch databases dynamically according to the user id who has logged in, each user has to upload a database associated with their login id ,once logged in the system should be able to switch to that uploaded database

This is the code so far

```
              $hostname='localhost';
              $username='root';
              $password='';
              $database='karonlabs_applications';

              /*DEFAULT DATABASE with a table that contains user id */
              $db=new mysqli($hostname,$username, $password,$database);

                 if ($db) { 


           echo 'Connected';


           }else{
               echo 'Cannot connect';
           }

          /* So here my client can be give a database .sql file which he has to upload after signing into the dashboard with credentials from the first database, so what i want is after my client uploading there database forexample like pos_system.sql the system should automatically switch to that uploaded database for the client ,NB: each client has to upload there own database and should access it basing on their login id*/

           if(mysqli_query($db, "USE `pos_system`")){
               echo 'connected to POS DB';
           }else{
               echo 'Cannot connect';
           }
```

Comment: You specify the db name when you create the connection object.  There are plenty of guides and questions (and the PHP manual) that show you how to connect to MySQL with PHP.

Comment: You need to post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thanks but how can i switch to the desired database once its uploaded by my client, that database is created basing on the user login id ,so what i want is that when a user logins in they are automatically switched to that database associated with their login id

Comment: We can't write your entire application for you.  You need to have some sort of starting point.  Put together something where a user is able to log in and you pull the desired database name from their user record and you store that to a variable.  Once you have that, this _might_ be answerable.

Comment: okay its just that my code is too long it cannot fit in the comment box

Comment: Code goes _in your question_, not in comments.  Before you go any further, I suggest you read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can do something like this:

In php file that verifies username and passowrd, do follwoing:

```
getUsersDB ($user, $password) {
   $db = new mysqli("dbServer", "admin_user", "admin_password", "users");

   if ($db->connect_errno) { /* handle the error */ }

    $user = $mysqli->query("SELECT userName FROM users");
    if ($user === FALSE) { /* handle the error */ }
    else { /* verify users passowrd */ }

    $userDB = $db->query("SELECT database FROM users WHERE user = $user") === TRUE);
    if ($userDB === TRUE) {
        $db->close();
        return $userDB;
    }
}
```

In file where user gets to his database you do:

```
/* have login scirpt */
$userDB = getUserDB ($user, $password);
$db = new mysqli("dbServer", $user, $userPassword, $userDB);
```

I hope this helps!!!

Comment: I get call to unidentified function for this script  /* have login scirpt */
$userDB = getUserDB ($user, $password);
$db = new mysqli("dbServer", $user, $userPassword, $userDB);

Answer (score 1):

### How does connection work

When you create a connection from PHP script to (MySQL) database, you specify (among other things) database name. Your script establish connection to DB server and **connect** to database you specified.

For example [`mysqli_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php):

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
```

Or object-oriented version:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
```

Notice the last **my_db** parameter.

From this moment on, you are connected and **working** on database called **my_db**.
Every query you send to your database afterwards, while you are connected with specified credentials is executed *on connected database*.

### How to switch database

Best practice is executing [`USE dbname;`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/use.html) query, but how?

Let's assume, you have access to two databases on one server:

- db1 (your database)
- db2 (client's database)

Initially, you connect to database `db1` with [`mysqli_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) (so you HAVE TO be connected first):

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "db1");
```

Then, you want to switch to database `db2`.
Simple send SQL command from PHP with [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), exactly the same as when you are executing `SELECT`s, `UPDATE`s, `INSERT`s... and other commands.

Connected to `db1` you do:

```
mysqli_query($link, "USE `db2`");
```

`$link` is your connection, created in first step. If you are using object-oriented version, then it would be:

```
$mysqli->query("USE `db2`");
```

Now you are connected to `db2` and every query **AFTER** [`USE db2;`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/use.html) is executed on `db2` database.

But, please, keep in mind that, if you close the connection and connect to `db1` again, with code from first step, you *have to* use [`USE db2;`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/use.html) again. 
So *[`USE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/use.html)* is helpful, but sometimes it is better closing connection to `db1` and connect directly to `db2`.
Depends on how often you need to change database in time of executing the script.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) helps to improve the quality of your response. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: thanks erik the thing is am having a table from another database which contains user login id and password,as for my company we are to create our clients a new database with their client login id  so that they can login into their account and upload that database so wat i want is when they upload the database ,their client user login id should start communicating with that database they have uploaded

Comment: thanks mate for that great idea, then how do i upload an .sql database file because its that second database a user has to upload when they have logged into their database hence its the database that has to be switched to basing on his login id ,and so each client has to upload there own database

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting using PDO, you can try this:

```
// Connect to the first database
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=HOST_NAME;dbname=DATABASE1", USER_NAME, PASSWORD, [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"]);


// Change to next database
$pdo->exec("use DATABASE2");
```

You can initially prepare a connection without even specifying a database, just remove this `;dbname=DATABASE1` from connection string, and just use `$pdo->exec("use DATABASE_NAME");`

For MySQLi, you can use this to switch database:

```
$conn->query("use DATABASE2");
```

Comment: Thanks Amir but am not yet familiar with PDO, how can i do that using Core PHP

Comment: Core PHP must connect to MySQL using a extension, such as `PDO`, `mysqli` etc, which one are you using

Comment: am using $conn=mysqli_connect();